# Amazon web services phpmyadmin: The mbstring extension is missing

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have installed phpMyAdmin on the hand of this tutorial: 
https://gist.github.com/suvozit/8998731
and connected my RDS instance as host in the /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file.

Now I got the following error when I visit *example.com/phpmyadmin/index.php*:

*The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.*

So I searched the internet for this error and people came with the following solution, which I tried:

**Install the php-mbstring extension:**

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

When I enter this command the proces starts but gives the following lines back:

```
-> Processing Conflict: php55-common-5.5.24-1.100.amzn1.x86_64 php-common <5.5.24-1.100.amzn1 conflict
-> Processing Conflict: php55-mbstring-5.5.24-1.100.amzn1.x86_64 php-mbstring <5.5.24-1.100.amzn1 conflict
-> Processing Conflict: php56-common-5.6.8-1.111.amzn1.x86_64 php-common <5.5.22-1.98 conflict

-> Ready to resolve dependencies
Error: php55-mbstring conflicts with php-mbstring 5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php55-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
  You could try: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

$ php -v returns:

```
PHP 5.6.8 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 18:04:37) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to install the PHP 5.6 version as superuser.

`sudo yum install php56-mbstring`

Comment: Done that, but it says that it's already installed, so I don't understand why the error is there that it is missing..

Comment: Can you please tell me what version of php you are running, as I think you have been installing files for two different versions. type ```php -v```

Comment: That could be possible. Check my output in my question.

Comment: Try doing ```yum install php56-mbstring``` instead as you are using PHP 5.6 not PHP 5.5. You will need to do the same for any other libraries you installed using the php55-* prefix.

Comment: Thanks! This works. Do you know how I can remove the older installed extensions?

Comment: You can simply run ```yum remove php55-*```.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was with the package conflict. So when installing php-gd you need to specify the version. I fixed it by running:
**sudo yum install php55-gd**

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only had to restart the httpd service:

```
service httpd restart
```